# Why is "gruntjs" task runner named "grunt"

Tags: gruntjs

Usually, I believe, the name of a library or tool carries an interesting and insightful meaning or very witty sense.

For example, **phantom**js is about testing with a browser that behaves like a phantom.

gruntjs must be named for a reason, I hope, and I expected it's explained in [their homepage](http://gruntjs.com/), but no luck. Does anyone know why it is **grunt**js, not something else?

Comment: A guess: boring, repetitive work is often called ["grunt work"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grunt+work), so a tool that automates it for you might logically be called Grunt.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about where a tool got its name, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing from what have been already commented by @explunit, a "[grunt work](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grunt+work)" is some boring and repetitive work. That explains their description in the [Grunt homepage](http://gruntjs.com/), as you state that have seen:

> ### Why use a task runner?
>
> In one word: automation. The less work you have
>   to do when performing repetitive tasks like minification, compilation,
>   unit testing, linting, etc, the easier your job becomes. After you've
>   configured it, a task runner can do most of that mundane work for
>   you—and your team—with basically zero effort.